# php soap empty output

Tags: php, soap

I'm an experienced PHP programmer but I have actually no clue about SOAP. Now I must use it because my customer needs an automatic generating of DHL batch labels. I need some simple and effective help.

So I send a raw XML request to DHL, I have copied the message from their sample programm but I get always an empty result (no error). My PHP code goes like:

```
require_once('nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');

$endpoint = "https://test-intraship.dhl.com/intraship.57/jsp/Login_WS.jsp";

$client = new nusoap_client($endpoint, false);

$msg = $client->serializeEnvelope("
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\"
 xmlns:cis=\"http://dhl.de/webservice/cisbase\" xmlns:de=\"http://de.ws.intraship\">
<soap:Header>
<cis:Authentification><cis:user>bzalewski</cis:user>

(...) 

");

$result=$client->send($msg, $endpoint);

echo $result;
```

As said, the message is just copied so it must be OK. 
I tried alternatively with another endpoint: http://test-intraship.dhl.com/ws/1_0/ISService/DE.wsdl, but also no result (no error).

Please help.

Comment: Are you required to use nusoap? if not, and if you are using php 5, try using php's inbuilt soap functions (soap_client)..it has better error reporting and is really much more stable than nusoap which was meant for php 4..

Comment: @Raidenace: how do I send a raw XML with PHP5? I tried but it didn't work as I don't know, what I am supposed to write as "Location" and "URI". In my question, you can see what the two addresses are. But what about namespace? The DHL documentation is pretty bad.

Comment: I have added an answer with a sample working code against the WDL you posted. Check it out..hope it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `soap_client` you do not need to pass raw `XML`. Instead you look at the `WSDL` and decide which web service function you want to call, and what parameters it needs. Then you create a soap client object, by passing the wsdl url and whether you want tracing or not (it helps to debug and stuff). Then use this soap client object to call whichever web service function you want to call. If there are parameters needed for the function call, pass them as an array. I have posted a sample code below which uses the `WSDL` you provided and calls its `getVersion` function. Note that this function does not need arguments so I am not passing anything. Hope this helps you get started..

```
<?
$client = new SoapClient('http://test-intraship.dhl.com/ws/1_0/ISService/DE.wsdl', array('trace' => 1));
$res = $client->getVersion();
print_r($res); 
?>
```

This returns following value from the DHL web service:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Version] => stdClass Object
        (
            [majorRelease] => 1
            [minorRelease] => 0
            [build] => 14
        )

)
```

Comment: There is one question more: how do I send my XML request?

Comment: Do you mean how you submit the request to the web service? If you have the wsdl for the webservice, all you need to do is just pass it to the soap_client. The soap_client will automatically figure out the endpoint and all other details from a correct WSDL url

Comment: do you know the function name to generate batch labels and the wsdl url for the web service that contains that function?

Comment: createShipmentDD, as I suppose

Comment: Use the code I have above, replace `$client->getVersion();` with `$client->createShipmentDD();`. As its arguments pass an array of all the fields you need to provide to the webservice

Answer (score 1):

Does the web server respond with a status 200? You said you get an empty response right?

Use this free GUI tool (http://webservicestudio.codeplex.com/) to make webservice call and visualize. You can easily load up the WSDL and start making calls.

By the way working 2 jobs and study is good stuff man! Keep it up.